# Swagger-ui applying unwanted encoding in the curl of a POST request

Tags: post, encoding, django-rest-framework, swagger, openapi

I am using OpenAPI3.0.2 in swagger and if I want to document my POST call with:

```
paths:
  /<myPath>
    post: 
      tags: 
        - <myTag>
      summary: <mySummary>
      description: <myDescription>
      operationId: <myID>
      requestBody:
        description: <myDescription>
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema: 
              oneOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/<schema1>'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/<schema2>'
```

and schema:

```
components:
  schemas:
    <schema1>:
      type: object
      properties:
        example1:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
        pageSize:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        page:
          type: integer
          format: int64
    <schema2>:
      type: object
      properties:
        example2:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
        pageSize:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        page:
          type: integer
          format: int64
```

My example value {example1:[test]} gets encoded to:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/<myPath>" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "0=%7B&1=e&2=x&3=a&4=m&5=p&6=l&7=e&8=1&9=%3A&10=%5B&11=t&12=e&13=s&14=t&15=%5D&16=%7D"
```

which results in this on the server-side:

```
<QueryDict: {'0': ['{'], '1': ['e'], '2': ['x'], '3': ['a'], '4': ['m'], '5': ['p'], '6': ['l'], '7': ['e'], '8': ['1'], '9': ['}']}>
```

instead of `<QueryDict: {'example1': ['test']}>`

I want to give information to the POST section of my request (which works with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). Because ultimately I want to read this out with `request_source.getlist` in my django server.

I already tried adding encoding information in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded like:

```
encoding:
  payload:
    contentType: application/json
```

but without success

Comment: Can you also post the <schema> definition? What version of Swagger UI do you use? (Open the browser dev tools, switch to the Console tab and evaluate `versions`).

Comment: I've added the schema to my post.
I am running swagger-editor@3.6.36 locally (from github)

Comment: I discovered that the problem is only present if I make use of the `oneOf:` atribute in the schema. Deleting these or replecing it with `anyOf` solves the issue. This seems like a bug ?

Comment: What data exactly do you enter for "Request body" during "try it out"?